# Are there non-trivial Foldable or Traversable instances that don't look like containers?

Tags: haskell, traversal, fold

There are lots of functors that look like containers (lists, sequences, maps, etc.), and many others that don't (state transformers, `IO`, parsers, etc.). I've not yet seen any non-trivial `Foldable` or `Traversable` instances that don't look like containers (at least if you squint a bit). Do any exist? If not, I'd love to get a better understanding of why they can't.

Comment: Well, if you [squint a bit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList) then _any_ `Foldable` will necessarily look like a list.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that isn't quite true, since a `Foldable` could extend indefinitely in both directions. But I'm interested in the underlying intuition. It seems mostly to have to do with the ability to directly fold over the thing without anything else happening in between, but that's not really very formal.

Comment: What about things like `data Prod1 f g a = P1 (f a) (g a); newtype Comp f g a = Comp (f (g a)); data Sum1 f g a = L1 (f a) | R1 (g a)`? These all have an `instance (Foldable f, Foldable g) => Foldable (X f g)`; I would consider these non trivial. (I believe but haven't checked they all have law-abiding instances).

Comment: @user2407038, I don't see how you could build anything out of those that doesn't look like a container.

Comment: Building on the answer of Daniel Wagner, you can write `StateT` as `newtype StateT s m a = St { runSt :: (((->) s) :.: m :.: ((,) s)) a }`, where `:.:` is `Comp`. If you agree that `StateT` is a non trivial Foldable, then you can indeed build a non-trivial Foldable from these. This relies on the `Finite a => Foldable ((->) a)` to qualify as a "non-trivial" Foldable, which will also looks like a container, if you squint hard enough (for example `(->) Natural` could be a representation of a list). I think the answer is based mainly on how you define 'container'.

Comment: Well anything can have a Foldable instance with `toList x = []`. I don't know what you mean by "non-trivial"; if you try to formalize it you may find that it is that condition which forces your functor to be "container-like". Traversable is a lot more interesting.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Every valid `Traversable f` is isomorphic to `Normal s` for some `s :: Nat -> *` where

```
data Normal (s :: Nat -> *) (x :: *) where  -- Normal is Girard's terminology
  (:-) :: s n -> Vec n x -> Normal s x

data Nat = Zero | Suc Nat

data Vec (n :: Nat) (x :: *) where
  Nil   :: Vec Zero n
  (:::) :: x -> Vec n x -> Vec (Suc n) x
```

but it's not at all trivial to implement the iso in Haskell (but it's worth a go with full dependent types). Morally, the `s` you pick is

```
data {- not really -} ShapeSize (f :: * -> *) (n :: Nat) where
  Sized :: pi (xs :: f ()) -> ShapeSize f (length xs)
```

and the two directions of the iso separate and recombine shape and contents. The shape of a thing is given just by `fmap (const ())`, and the key point is that the length of the shape of an `f x` is the length of the `f x` itself.

Vectors are traversable in the visit-each-once-left-to-right sense. Normals are traversable exactly in by preserving the shape (hence the size) and traversing the vector of elements. To be traversable is to have finitely many element positions arranged in a linear order: isomorphism to a normal functor exactly exposes the elements in their linear order. Correspondingly, every `Traversable` structure is a (finitary) container: they have a set of shapes-with-size and a corresponding notion of position given by the initial segment of the natural numbers strictly less than the size.

The `Foldable` things are also finitary and they keep things in an order (there is a sensible `toList`), but they are not guaranteed to be `Functor`s, so they don't have such a crisp notion of *shape*. In that sense (the sense of "container" defined by my colleagues Abbott, Altenkirch and Ghani), they do not necessarily admit a shapes-and-positions characterization and are thus not containers. If you're lucky, some of them may be containers upto some quotient. Indeed `Foldable` exists to allow processing of structures like `Set` whose internal structure is intended to be a secret, and certainly depends on ordering information about the elements which is not necessarily respected by traversing operations. Exactly what constitutes a well behaved `Foldable` is rather a moot point, however: I won't quibble with the pragmatic benefits of that library design choice, but I could wish for a clearer specification.

Comment: Why does the first argument to `ShapeSize` have kind `*->*` when it is used only as `f ()`? Is the reason for that missing from the pseudo-translation to Haskell? Also, Haskell isn't so fussy about finiteness, allowing things like `Traversable []` and `Traversable Tree`. How does that affect things?

Comment: (a) The first argument to ShapeSize is in `* -> *` because so is the argument of `Traversable` that's being modelled; (b) `Traversable` doesn't make sense (`undefined` is a form of nonsense) for infinite structures, but it is common and inevitable Haskeller hypocrisy to pretend we mean just the finite fragment of an infinite type whenever it suits us, e.g. `Eq` instances. If ever we did separate data and codata, only the data would be `Traversable`.

Comment: On the other hand, one abomination (infinite traversable) mixes with another (lazy state) to produce perfectly sensible `mapAccumL` and `mapAccumR` for infinite structures.

Comment: But perhaps the perfectly sensible things also admit perfectly sensible constructions.

Comment: In your lectures extension of a `Normal` is not the part of the definition of `Normal`, and `Foldable` then is isomorphic to `Normal`, since`normalT` is defined via `sizeT`, which is defined via `crush`, which is `foldMap`. (Whilst extension of a `Normal` is not isomorphic to `Foldable`, since there is no `fmap`). So what definition of `Normal` is pedantically precise?

Comment: @user3237465 crush is only foldMapDefault for Traversable; my lecture notes say nothing about Foldable. You are kicking up dust which isn't there.

Comment: Sure, I just mean that if `Foldable` would be there, then every `Foldable` [would](https://github.com/effectfully/DataData/blob/master/First.agda#L274) give raise to a `Normal` (I said "isomorphic", but that was wrong — two definitions of `Normal` messed up in my head).

Comment: @user3237465, what lectures are you referring to? Also, the link in your last comment is broken.

Comment: @dfeuer, [SSGEP-DataData](https://github.com/pigworker/SSGEP-DataData) ones. [Here](https://github.com/effectfully/DataData/blob/fecdf99394fe665c501fcf2a32c6e02992271656/Structures/Normal.agda#L81) is a working link.

Answer (score 10):

Well, with the help of [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe), one could potentially write `Foldable` and `Traversable` instances for state transformers over finite state spaces. The idea would be roughly similar to the `Foldable` and `Traversable` instances for functions: run the function everywhere for `Foldable` and make a lookup table for `Traversable`. Thus:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Map
import Data.Universe

-- e.g. `m ~ Identity` satisfies these constraints
instance (Finite s, Foldable m, Monad m) => Foldable (StateT s m) where
    foldMap f m = mconcat [foldMap f (evalStateT m s) | s <- universeF]

fromTable :: (Finite s, Ord s) => [m (a, s)] -> StateT s m a
fromTable vs = StateT (fromList (zip universeF vs) !)

float :: (Traversable m, Applicative f) => m (f a, s) -> f (m (a, s))
float = traverse (\(fa, s) -> fmap (\a -> (a, s)) fa)

instance (Finite s, Ord s, Traversable m, Monad m) => Traversable (StateT s m) where
    sequenceA m = fromTable <$> traverse (float . runStateT m) universeF
```

I'm not sure whether this makes sense. If it does, I think I would be happy to add it to the package; what do you think?

Comment: I think by then you have a container, and those instances sound sensible.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think it’s actually Foldable or Traversible, but MonadRandom is an example of something that could be, functioning like an infinite list, but which doesn't look any more like a container than anything else that’s foldable.  Conceptually, it’s a random variable.