# Why isn't the state monad traversable?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad, traversable

Intuitively, it seems to me that one could use traverse with a state monad, for example:

```
traverse (\a -> [a, a+1]) (state (\s -> (1, s + 1))) 
  = [state (\s -> (1, s + 1), state (\s -> (2, s + 1)]
```

But the state monad doesn't implement the Traversable typeclass. Why is that? I've tried to figure out a way to implement traverse for the state monad, and it seems that the difficulty is to extract the result of the state monad in order to pass it to the function given as first argument of traverse. Is it impossible?

Comment: See [Are there non-trivial Foldable or Traversable instances that don't look like containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812400/are-there-non-trivial-foldable-or-traversable-instances-that-dont-look-like-con), and in particular pigworker's answer.

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this is a duplicate of dfeuer's suggested link, since answer there discuss this exact thing. Guillaume, do you have any objection?

Comment: @DanielWagner: It's a good idea to link the two questions, but I wouldn't mark this one as a duplicate of the other. This one is more specifically about the state monad (and perhaps because of it, is more accessible to me at least). Also the answers below and your's to the link question go in opposite directions (if I understand them well). The answers below explain why traversing a state monad is impossible, while in your answer to the linked question you propose a way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To implement `Traversable t`, you need to implement a function of this type:

```
sequenceA :: forall f a. Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

When `t` is `State s`, this becomes:

```
sequenceA :: forall f a. Applicative f => State s (f a) -> f (State s a)
```

Obviously we can't write an implementation *for all `s`*, since we'd have to know either how to create an `s` or an `f a` out of nothing in order to proceed. That would be a contradiction.

But it's possible to write an instance that satisfies the type *for certain classes of `s`*. If we assume that `s` is a `Monoid`, we could do this:

```
instance (Monoid m) => Traversable (State m) where
  sequenceA (State run) = fmap (\a -> State (\s' -> (mappend s s', a)) fa 
    where (s, fa) = run mempty
```

But this does *not* satisfy the `Traversable` laws. One of the laws is:

```
traverse Identity = Identity
```

(recall that `traverse f = sequence . fmap f`)

This law clearly doesn't hold because the output action `mappend`s whereas the input action did not. OK, how about we just don't `mappend`:

```
instance (Monoid m) => Traversable (State m) where
  sequenceA (State run) = fmap (\a -> State (\_ -> (s, a)) fa 
    where (s, fa) = run mempty
```

That doesn't help, since now the output action ignores its input and subsitutes `mempty` whereas the input action did not.

This doesn't mean that there aren't types `s` for which we couldn't construct a lawful `Traverse (State s)` instance. For example, `State ()` reduces to `Identity`, which absolutely is traversable.

And if we can do `State ()`, why not `State Bool`? We can just `runState` the original action at *both* `True` and `False`, store the result in a map, and then have the resulting state action perform a lookup in that map. This works for any *finitely enumerable* state domain. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32812758/791604) for details.

Comment: Are you sure there's no [interesting instances](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32812758/791604)?

Answer (score 5):

Being `Traversable` requires being `Foldable`; but `State` monad is not - you cannot `foldMap` it, because its value is simple not here.

```
type State s = StateT s Indentity
newtype StateT s m a = State { runState :: s -> m (s, a) }
```

As you can see, there is no immediate `a` to fold over here, its only result of the function.

Comment: It can be made `Foldable` in a trivial way; anything of kind `* -> *` can. `instance Foldable (StateT s m) where foldMap _ _ = mempty`. But `Traversable` is much more demanding.

Comment: I show how to implement `Foldable` and `Traversable` for `State` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32812758/791604).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is indeed impossible. Consider the following definition of `State`:

```hs
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

To [`extract`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.2.7.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:extract) the value this data type we would first need to supply some state.

We can create a specialized `extract` function if we know the type of the state. For example:

```hs
extract' :: State () a -> a
extract' (State f) = f ()

extractT :: State Bool a -> a
extractT (State f) = f True

extractF :: State Bool a -> a
extractF (State f) = f False
```

However, we can't create a generic extract function. For example:

```hs
extract :: State s a -> a
extract (State f) = f undefined
```

The above `extract` function is generic. The only state we can supply is ⊥ which is incorrect. It is only safe if the function `f :: s -> (a, s)` passes along its input transparently (i.e. `f = (,) a` for some value `a`). However, `f` may take some state and use it to generate some value and a new state. Hence, `f` may use its input non-transparently and if the input is ⊥ then we get an error.

Thus, we cannot create a generic `extract` function for the `State` data type.

Now, for a data type to be an instance of `Traversable` it first needs to be an instance of `Foldable`. Hence, to make `State` an instance of `Traversable` we first need to define the following instance:

```hs
instance Foldable (State s) where
    foldMap f (State g) = mempty
    -- or
    foldMap f (State g) = let x = f (extract g) in mconcat [x]
    -- or
    foldMap f (State g) = let x = f (extract g) in mconcat [x,x]
    -- or
    foldMap f (State g) = let x = f (extract g) in mconcat [x,x,x]
    -- ad infinitum
```

Note that `foldMap` has the type `Monoid m => (a -> m) -> State s a -> m`. Hence, the expression `foldMap f (State g)` must return a value of the type `Monoid m => m`. Trivially, we can always return `mempty` by defining `foldMap = const (const mempty)`. However, in my humble opinion this is incorrect because:

1. We aren't really folding anything by always returning `mempty`.
2. Every data type can be trivially made an instance of `Foldable` by always returning `mempty`.

The only other way to produce a value of the type `Monoid m => m` is to apply `f` to some value `x` of the type `a`. However, we don't have any value of the type `a`. If we could `extract` the value `a` from `State s a` then we could apply `f` to that value, but we already proved that it's not possibly to define a generic `extract` function for `State s a` that never crashes.

Thus, `State s` cannot be made an instance of `Foldable` and consequently it cannot be an instance of `Traversable`.

Comment: I don't think "`extract` cannot be defined" implies "`foldMap` cannot be defined". For example, I can't write `extract :: Unit a -> a` where `data Unit a = Unit`, but I can write `foldMap f _ = mempty`.

Comment: @DanielWagner We are talking about the state monad. I never said that `foldMap` can't be defined for __any__ data type if `extract` cannot be defined for that data type.

Comment: What is special about `State` that means I *must* be able to define `extract` in order to define `foldMap`? In other words, if there are types where I can define `foldMap` without `extract`, why should I believe that I can't do it for `State`?

Comment: Or, more to the point: `State Void a` is morally the same thing as `Unit a`. So why should I believe I can't define `foldMap` for `State Void a`, even though I can't define `extract` for `State Void a`?

Comment: So, you want to define `foldMap f (State g) = mempty`? You could do that, and I see what you are getting at (in my answer I said that `foldMap` can __only__ be defined in terms of `extract` which is indeed false). In fact, you could trivially make any data type an instance of `Foldable` by defining `foldMap = const (const mempty)`. However, that's not very useful. You aren't "folding" over any data structure when you define `foldMap` as `const (const mempty)`. Hence, I would say that not only is that definition trivial but also wrong. Nevertheless, thank you for pointing that out. I'll update.

Comment: I absolutely don't want to define `foldMap f (State g) = mempty`. And I don't agree that the proposed list of instances covers all the possibilities, either. I agree that "if we could `extract` the value `a` from `State s a` then we could apply `f` to that value", but I don't agree that the implication goes the other way, that is, that `foldMap` *must* use `extract` to get something to apply `f` to. Your argument needs a lot of work to be made convincing!

Answer (score 1):

Such a function can't exist.

You are asking for a function with this signature:

```
trav :: (a -> [a]) -> (s -> (a,s)) -> [ s -> (a,s) ]
```

That is, given a function `f :: a -> [a]` and a state computation, `trav` returns a list. In particular, if I give you `f` and a state computation, you should be able tell me if the result list is null or not.

Now consider this `f`:

```
f :: Int -> [Int]
f 0 = []
f a = [a]
```

And try to evaluate `trav f (\s -> (s,s))` or even try to determine if it is the empty list.

You can write this function:

```
trav' :: [ a -> a ] -> (s -> (a,s)) -> [ s -> (a,s) ]
```

because the resulting list will always have the same length.

Comment: You say that the function `trav` can't exist and then you ask the reader to try to evaluate `trav f (\s -> (s, s))`. Your answer started out well but you just hand waved your conclusion.

Comment: I'm asking the OP to tell me what the result should be to demonstrate that the concept of what `trav` should do is ill-defined. Do you have any suggestions of how to improve my answer?

Comment: I take your challenge. I declare that `trav f (\s -> (s, s))` has length `0`. Now what?