# Implement Scala Cats Traverse for State

Tags: scala, scala-cats, state-monad, traversable

I've been writing my own version of Scala Cats (to assist others when learning this library).
I've implemented my own versions of most type classes, but am stuck with a custom implementation of Traverse for State. The function to implement is:

```
def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, S, A, B](fa: State[S, A])(f: A => G[B]): G[State[S, B]]
```

As a starter, I asked ChatGPT for an implementation in Scala Cats (since of course, it does not know my own library). A valid (simple) implementation in Cats should help me write a version in my own library.
However, ChatGPT has failed me, with over-complicated solutions using the likes of StateT (of which currently I do not have an equivalent in my library).
Also, the versions produced by ChatGPT do not compile.

One simple suggestion is the following, but does not compile:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, S, A, B](fa: State[S, A])(f: A => G[B]): G[State[S, B]] = {
  val gb: G[B] =
    fa.runA _ andThen f

  val stateB: G[State[S, B]] =
    gb.map(b => State(s => (s, b)))

  stateB
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `Traversable` (`Traverse` in Cats) is `Foldable`.

`State` is `Applicative` and `Monad` but not `Foldable` or `Traversable`

[Why isn't the state monad traversable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736518/why-isnt-the-state-monad-traversable)

[Are there non-trivial Foldable or Traversable instances that don't look like containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812400/are-there-non-trivial-foldable-or-traversable-instances-that-dont-look-like-con) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821966/5249621))

You can check that in Cats summoning `Applicative[State[S, *]]` and `Monad[State[S, *]]` compile but `Foldable[State[S, *]]` or `Traverse[State[S, *]]` doesn't.

`State[S, A]` is basically a function `S => (S, A)` (if we ignore wrapping, `StateT`, and `Eval`).

If `State` were a `Foldable` you'd be able to implement

```
def foldMap[S, A, B: Monoid](fa: S => (S, A))(f: A => B): B
// or
def foldLeft[S, A, B](fa: S => (S, A), b: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B
```

If `State` were a `Traversable` you'd be able to implement

```
def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, S, A, B](fa: S => (S, A))(f: A => G[B]): G[S => (S, B)]
// or
def sequence[G[_]: Applicative, A](fga: S => (S, G[A])): G[S => (S, A)]
```

Combining `S => (S, A)` and `A => G[B]` you can have `S => (S, G[B])` but how to get `G[S => (S, B)]` if you only can do `def ap[A, B](ff: G[A => B])(fa: G[A]): G[B]` and `def pure[A](x: A): G[A]`?

`Foldable` means you can fold a structure into a value. `Traversable` means you can traverse a structure executing some applicative effect in every node of the structure. `State` is like a function, you can't fold it or traverse it.

Comment: Many thanks. A very nice explanation.
It did not dawn on me, that I could not find a `State` instance for `Traverse` within the Cats library; but then again, even though it is a brilliant library, sometimes it takes a while to find in the source code, what one is looking for.

Comment: What is interesting, is that when I failed to write a `State` instance for `Traverse`, at the time thinking it was  possible, I asked ChatGPT, and not only did it respond "yes", it suggested a possible implementation (which as mentioned, did not compile).

Comment: @DAinslie That's why ChatGPT is banned at SO https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned ChatGPT generates answers looking like human answers, not necessarily correct ones.

Comment: @DAinslie https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/124ocqh/scala_and_chatgpt/