# Vector creation safety

Tags: arrays, haskell, vector, higher-rank-types, traversable

This question is actually a small lattice of very closely related questions; I don't think it makes much sense to break it up as yet.

One of the fundamental ways to create a [`Vector`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/vector-0.12.0.1/Data-Vector.html#t:Vector) is using [`unsafeFreeze`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/vector-0.12.0.1/Data-Vector.html#v:unsafeFreeze). As its name suggests, `unsafeFreeze` is truly unsafe. In particular, nothing prevents the `MVector` passed to `unsafeFreeze` from being modified after it is frozen. This leads to two different problems:

1. It can make "immutable" vectors change in value. This is just the sort of spooky action at a distance Haskell generally shuns.
2. Modifying a frozen vector can (at least potentially) confuse the garbage collector. There is no documented guarantee that the garbage collector will scan frozen arrays to ensure their contents are evacuated. More generally, mutating vectors while they are frozen is absolutely forbidden, and the result of doing so is utterly unspecified.

The [`vector`](https://www.stackage.org/package/vector) package[1] offers two efficient, seemingly safe, primitives for creating immutable vectors: [`create`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/vector-0.12.0.1/Data-Vector.html#v:create) and [`createT`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/vector-0.12.0.1/Data-Vector.html#v:createT):

```
create :: (forall s. ST s (MVector s a)) -> Vector a
createT :: Traversable t => (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s a))) -> t (Vector a)
```

Ignoring vector fusion business, the basic implementations look like

```
create m = runST $ m >>= unsafeFreeze
createT m = runST $ m >>= traverse unsafeFreeze
```

`create` is pretty clearly safe. It runs the given `ST s` action, which must create a fresh `MVector s` (the type of `runST` ensures it can't use an existing one, and also ensures that `fixST` can't play any funny tricks), freezes it, and returns the frozen vector.

`createT` is pretty clearly safe when the `Traversable` instance is lawful. With lists, for example, `createT m` runs an action producing a list of `MVector`s, then freezes them all. Parametricity in `s` then seems sufficient, as for `create`, to ensure nothing bad happens. Note that the action *may* create a list with multiple copies of the same `MVector`. These will be frozen twice, but there shouldn't be any harm in that. Lawful `Traversable` instances [all look pretty much like decorated lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821966/1477667), so they should behave similarly. Now I finally reach my first question:

**Is `createT` safe when used with an unlawful `Traversable` instance?**

Unlawfully dropping, duplicating or rearranging some elements or changing decorations (violating the identity law) doesn't pose any obvious difficulty. Parametricity prevents any interesting violations of the naturality law, so that's out. I haven't been able to find a way to cause trouble by violating the composition law or totality, but that is no guarantee that there isn't one.

One obvious way to generalize `createT` is to allow the user to pass their own traversal function:

```
createTOf
  :: (forall f x y. Applicative f => (x -> f y) -> t x -> f (u y))
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s a))) -> u (Vector a)
createTOf trav m = runST $ m >>= trav unsafeFreeze
```

Note that I've allowed the traversal to change the container type from `t` to `u`. This allows the user to, for example, produce a `Vector (MVector s a)` but get back a `[Vector a]`. When `t ~ u`, this is obviously just as safe as `createT` with an unlawful `Traversable` instance. Does the extra flexibility of changing the "container" type reduce safety? **Edit:** I just realized I can answer this one: no, it makes no difference. See [2] below for an explanation.

When we use `createT`, we might not actually want a container of vectors; perhaps we want to traverse that container to get something else. We can write something like

```
traverse f <$> createT m
```

The extra type flexibility of `createTOf` means we don't necessarily have a `Traversable` on our hands, and can't necessarily do this. But using the composition law for `Traversable`, we can integrate this traversal into the creation function:

```
createTOfThen
  :: Applicative g
  => (forall f x y. Applicative f => (x -> f y) -> t x -> f (u y))
  -> (Vector a -> g b)
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s a)))
  -> g (u b)
createTOfThen trav f m =
  runST $ m >>= getCompose . trav (Compose . fmap f . unsafeFreeze)
```

**Is `createTOfThen` safe if `trav` is not a lawful traversal?**

---

I did say I'd be talking about a lattice, right? The next question is how much (if at all) we can weaken the polymorphism of the traversal without causing trouble. Everything will typecheck even if the traversal is only required to be polymorphic in `s`, but that's obviously unsafe, as it can interleave freezing with modification however it likes. 
Revealing to the that the end result holds `Vector` values seems likely to be harmless enough, but we surely can't let the traversal know *both* that it is operating in `ST s` *and* that it is handling `MVector s a` values. But could we let it know one of those facts? Fixing the `Applicative` would certainly be useful:

```
createTOf'
  :: (forall s x y. (x -> ST s y) -> t x -> ST s (u y))
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s a))) -> u (Vector a)

createTOfThen'
  :: Applicative g
  => (forall s x y. (x -> Compose (ST s) g y) -> t x -> Compose (ST s) g (u y))
  -> (Vector a -> g b)
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s a)))
  -> g (u b)
```

This would offer more efficient creation of things like vectors of vectors, as vectors can be traversed more efficiently in `ST` than in arbitrary `Applicative` functors. It would also reduce dependence on inlining, as we'd avoid dealing with the `Applicative` dictionary.

On the flip side, I suspect we can let the traversal know it's handling `MVector`s ... as long as we don't let it know what state thread they're associated with. This is sufficient to unbox them, and also (perhaps unfortunately) to get their sizes.

**Edit!** If the traversal is allowed to know that it's producing `Vector`s (which seems like the very least likely thing to be problematic), then `createTOfThen` can be implemented in terms of `createTOf`:

```
createTOfThen trav post m = getConst $
  createTOf (\f ->
    fmap Const . getCompose . (trav (Compose . fmap post . f))) m
```

---

Taking the lattice in a third direction, let's move on to rank-2 traversals. The `rank2classes` package offers its own [`Traversable`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.4/rank2classes-1.0.2/Rank2.html#t:Traversable) class, which I'll call `R2.Traversable`:

```
class (R2.Functor g, R2.Foldable g) => R2.Traversable g where
  R2.traverse :: Applicative m
              => (forall a. p a -> m (q a))
              -> g p -> m (g q)
```

We can play *exactly* the same games with this to produce *heterogeneous* containers of `Vector`s:

```
createTHet
  :: R2.Traversable t
  => (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s)))
  -> t Vector
createTHet m = runST $ m >>= R2.traverse unsafeFreeze

createTHetOf
  :: (forall h f g.
       (Applicative h => (forall x. f x -> h (g x)) -> t f -> h (u g)))
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s)))
  -> u Vector
createTHetOf trav m = runST $ m >>= trav unsafeFreeze

createTHetOfThen
  :: Applicative q
  => (forall h f g.
       (Applicative h => (forall x. f x -> h (g x)) -> t f -> h (u g)))
  -> (forall x. Vector x -> q (r x))
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s)))
  -> q (u r)
createTHetOfThen trav post m =
    runST $ m >>= getCompose . trav (Compose . fmap post . unsafeFreeze)
```

along with similar versions where the traversal is allowed to know it's working in `ST s`. I would *imagine* that the safety properties of the rank-2 versions are identical to those of the corresponding rank-1 versions, but I don't have a clue how one might go about proving such.

Just for fun, I think the top of my lattice is the following monstrosity. If any of these ideas are unsafe, this one probably is:

```
createTHetOfThen'
  :: (forall s1 s2.
       ((forall x. MVector s2 x -> Compose (ST s1) q (r x)) -> t (MVector s2) -> Compose (ST s1) q (u r)))
  -> (forall x. Vector x -> q (r x))
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s)))
  -> q (u r)
createTHetOfThen' trav post m =
    runST $ m >>= getCompose . trav (Compose . fmap post . unsafeFreeze)
```

---

[1] I've linked to Stackage because Hackage is down today. If I remember and have time, I'll fix up the links later.

[2] The proof comes from `Data.Functor.Sum`. Given a non-type-changing `createTOfSame`, we can write

```
createTOf
  :: (forall f a b. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (u b))
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s a)))
  -> u (Vector a)
createTOf trav m =
  case createTOfSame (\f (InL xs) -> InR <$> trav f xs)
                     (InL <$> m) of
    InR u -> u
```

This will actually be total, although the "traversal" is partial: we always case match on what we will surely find.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing this idea to the limit has actually helped me understand it better, and I'm now fairly well convinced that *all* of these functions are safe. Consider

```
createTOf
  :: (forall s1 s2.
       (MVector s1 a -> ST s2 (Vector a))
       -> t (MVector s1 a) -> ST s2 (u (Vector a)))
  -> (forall s. ST s (t (MVector s a)))
  -> u (Vector a)
createTOf trav m = runST $ m >>= trav unsafeFreeze
```

It's certainly quite a mouthful of a type signature! Let's focus in closely on the safety property we care about: that no `MVector` is mutated after it is frozen. The first thing we do is run `m` to produce something of type `t (MVector s a)`.

`t` is very mysterious right now. Is it a container? Is it some sort of action that produces vectors? We can't really say terribly much about what it *is*, but we *can* say some things about what `trav unsafeFreeze` *cannot* do with it. Let's start by breaking out the type signature of `trav`:

```
trav :: forall s1 s2.
        (MVector s1 a -> ST s2 (Vector a))
     -> t (MVector s1 a) -> ST s2 (u (Vector a)))
```

`trav` turns `t (MVector s1 a)` into `ST s2 (u (Vector a))`. If `t` has vectors in it, then those vectors live in state thread `s1`. The result, however, is an action in state thread `s2`. So `trav` cannot modify an `MVector`s it's given using the usual operations. It can only apply the function it takes (which will be `unsafeFreeze`), and use whatever machinery may ride in on `t`. What sort of machinery could ride in on `t`? Well, here's a silly example:

```
data T :: Type -> Type where
  T :: [ST s (MVector s a)] -> t (MVector s a)
```

Could `trav` interleave these `ST` actions with the freezes? No! Those `ST` actions match the `MVector`s, but they *don't* match the state thread `trav` operates in. So `trav` can't do anything with them whatsoever.